# Error try to run scala but it didn`t work

Tags: java, scala, shell

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> [init] error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/package.class)
[init] error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/runtime/package.class)

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.


Failed to initialize the REPL due to an unexpected error.
This is a bug, please, report it along with the error diagnostics printed below.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$codeParser$.applyRule(ExprTyper.scala:24)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$codeParser$.stmts(ExprTyper.scala:35)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$$anonfun$parse$2.apply(ExprTyper.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$$anonfun$parse$2.apply(ExprTyper.scala:42)
        at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter.withIncompleteHandler(Reporter.scala:51)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$class.parse(ExprTyper.scala:42)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$exprTyper$.parse(IMain.scala:1074)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.parse(IMain.scala:1078)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$showCodeIfDebugging$1.apply(IMain.scala:1168)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$showCodeIfDebugging$1.apply(IMain.scala:1168)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beSilentDuring(IMain.scala:238)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.showCodeIfDebugging(IMain.scala:1168)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compileAndSaveRun(IMain.scala:800)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.compile(IMain.scala:761)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:618)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:661)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietBind$1.apply(IMain.scala:660)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$quietBind$1.apply(IMain.scala:660)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:232)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietBind(IMain.scala:660)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(ILoop.scala:853)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoopInit$class.runThunks(ILoopInit.scala:122)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.runThunks(ILoop.scala:42)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoopInit$class.postInitialization(ILoopInit.scala:95)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.postInitialization(ILoop.scala:42)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoopInit$$anonfun$createAsyncListener$1.apply$mcV$sp(ILoopInit.scala:63)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoopInit$$anonfun$createAsyncListener$1.apply(ILoopInit.scala:60)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoopInit$$anonfun$createAsyncListener$1.apply(ILoopInit.scala:60)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$3.call(package.scala:40)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I`m doing a Udemy course and tried to run Scala but it didn`t work.
Maybe someone finds an solution and can help me.
I installed Java 8 but it still didn`t run properly. It tells me that I`m using Java 11 but I have no clue why?
Is there a better and simpler way to install Scala that does work for sure?
Just tell me

Comment: it says that you are using `scala 2.10.5` (a really old version of scala) and `jdk 11`. it's not even listed in [scala jdk compatibility](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html). Not sure which version is being used in the tutorial, but scala `2.13.x` and `3.3.x` are the active ones today

Comment: Using waybackmachine I found that JDK 11 requires minimum scala version of 2.10.7. If you or tutorial insist on using 2.10.5 you should try changing Java version. Sorry if this sounds pretentious but have you checked your PATH and JAVA_HOME?

Also since you're looking for simpler ways that will-just-work(tm) you could always just install IntelliJ Idea - it allows you to configure/download both JDK and Scala for a newly created project although I'm not sure how this will fit with what tutorial wants you to do

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact command line you used to start your session.